# Specify type of polymorphic function to pass it as argument

Tags: swift, swift2

I have function `curry` that takes a function `(A, B) -> C` as an argument, and returns `A -> B -> C`. It works fine on function `g(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int`. Also, I have function `f`, that is polymorphic, so its type is ambigous. Here is the code:

```
func g(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int { return a + b }

func f(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int { return a + b }
func f(a: Float, b: Float) -> Float { return a + b }

func curry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
  return { a in { b in f(a, b) } }
}

let curriedG = curry(g) //curriedG type Int -> Int -> Int

let curriedF = curry(f) //Error, Ambigous use of 'f(_:b:)'
```

It is obvious, that I can't do `curry(f)`, but, is there any way, so I could specify, that I want to use specific `f()` implementation?

**Why I need this.**
Because of initialisers. I want to curry specific initialiser, lets say `struct A` has two initialisers: `init(t: T, y: Y)` and `init(u: U, h: H)`, I want to curry one of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `f` is overloaded, you have to specify which `f` you want:

```
let curriedF = curry(f as (Float, Float) -> Float)
```

or, alternatively, what the result should be:

```
let curriedF = curry(f) as Float -> Float -> Float
```

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish `f(a a: Int) -> Int` and `f(_ a: Int) -> Int` in this manner?

Comment: @AlfredZien: I don't think so.