# Using overloaded functions as first class citizens

Tags: swift, first-class-functions

Suppose that we have several overloaded functions in one class:

```
func appendToABC(string s: String) -> String {
    return "ABC \(s)"
}

func appendToABC(duplicatedString s: String) -> String {
    return "ABC \(s)\(s)"
}
```

And we have some API that gets function as an argument:

```
func printString(function: (String) -> String) {
    print(function("ASD"))
}
```

How can we pass one of appendToABC functions as an argument to a printString function?

I've thought about wrapping the function with a closure, but it doesn't look nice

```
printString { appendToABC(duplicatedString: $0) }
```

Comment: It is possible if the functions differ in their argument or return types (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803888/specify-type-of-polymorphic-function-to-pass-it-as-argument). But I don't think it is possible if the functions differ *only* in the external parameter names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation in Swift. There is an [open proposal](https://github.com/DougGregor/swift-evolution/blob/generalized-naming/proposals/0000-generalized-naming.md) to address it. Currently the only solution is a closure.

Note that this is true of many things in Swift. You also can't refer to properties directly as functions, even though they behave like functions. You must use a closure. And even some free functions cannot be directly passed (`print` is the most common example).